# how can i obtain a pointer to $esp or $eip in order to exploit with house of force attack?

Tags: c, security, gdb, buffer-overflow

the probelm is that i want to obtain a pointer to the return addres of the main function in order to calculate the distance between my heap top chunk and the $eip store in the stack (for the house of force attack) . then i will override that $eip with the address of the "win function".

i searched the $eip with gdb and that is the result on my machine :

```
info frame  --> saved eip = 0xb7e1d286
                saved registers:  eip at 0xbffff12c

print $esp -->  $1 = (void * ) 0xbffff0d0
```

ok now i will show the code of the code to be exploited  where i tried to obtian that pointer to esp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define offset 18
void win()
{
  printf("Congratulations, you win!!! You successfully changed the code flow\n");
}

unsigned long get_sp(void)
{
    /* This function (suggested in alephOne's paper) prints the
       stack pointer using assembly code. */
    __asm__("movl %esp,%eax");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char *buf1, *buf2, *buf3 ;
   int *c ;
   int real_size ;

   if(argc != 4) return 0;

   printf("The goal of this attack is to execute the win function!!!\n") ;

   buf1 = malloc(256) ;
   strcpy(buf1, argv[1]) ;


   void * return_address = get_sp() + offset;
   void * stackp = get_sp();
   printf("return_address value is %p at register %p\n", &return_address,return_address);
   printf("stack_pointer at address %p\n and contain  %p ",(void  *)get_sp(),(void *)&stackp);
   real_size = malloc_usable_size(buf1) ;
   intptr_t *ptr_top = (intptr_t *) ((char *)buf1 + real_size - sizeof(long)) ;
   printf("Top chunck is: %p\n", ptr_top) ;

   //unsigned long evilsize = (unsigned long) return_address - sizeof(long)*4 - (unsigned long)ptr_top;
   //printf("evilsize is : %lu",evilsize);
   buf2 = malloc(strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 16)) ;
   buf3 = malloc(256) ;
   strcpy(buf3, argv[3]) ;

   //free(buf3) ;
   //free(buf2) ;
   //free(buf1) ;

   return 0;


}
```

the $esp printed is different with the one shown by gdb :

```
stack_pointer at address 0xbffff268 and contains 0xbffff274
```

why is it different? how can obtain it? thank you very much

Comment: It is different, because one is the address of some stack variable `stackp` and the other one is the stack pointer, as it was somewhere in the middle of the function `get_sp()`. These can hardly be the same, why do you expect them to be equal?

Comment: yeah, i was thinking they'd be the same!! thanks for the answer.. so, now, how can i calculate the "evil size" (the distance between the top chunk pointer in the heap and the $eip) ?